# Laravel Queue tasks getting killed

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, laravel-5.4, amazon-sqs

I am using `SQS` to upload my videos to the `S3 bucket` in the background. The queue works perfectly fine for small videos (`~40 MBs`). But, when I try to upload bigger videos (`say 70 MBs and more`) the queue operation gets killed.
Here's my queue operation's output:

```
vagrant@homestead:~/Laravel/video (master)*$ php artisan queue:work --tries=3
[2017-08-25 17:48:42] Processing: Laravel\Scout\Jobs\MakeSearchable
[2017-08-25 17:48:45] Processed:  Laravel\Scout\Jobs\MakeSearchable
[2017-08-25 17:48:51] Processing: App\Jobs\VideoUploadJob
Killed
vagrant@homestead:~/Laravel/youtube (master)*$ php artisan queue:work --tries=3
[2017-08-25 17:50:33] Processing: App\Jobs\VideoUploadJob
Killed
vagrant@homestead:~/Laravel/video (master)*$
```

Where do I need to change the setting?? Something on Laravel side or on SQS??
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 options. Either running out of memory or exceeding execution time.

Try `$ dmesg | grep php` This will show you more details

Increase `max_execution_time` and/or `memory_limit` in your php.ini file.